# What's the difference between Stereo 70 and Pulkovo stereo 70?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I was wondering, can anyone tell me the diffrence between Pulkovo_1942_Adj_58_Stereo_70 (3844) and Dealul Piscului-Stereo 70 (31700)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EPSG:3844, "Pulkovo 1942(58) / Stereo70" replaced EPSG:31700, "Dealul Piscului 1970 / Stereo 70". "Dealul Piscului 1970" as a geographic coordinate reference system never existed as a separate re-adjustment or realization but instead is an alias for "Pulkovo 1942(58)". "Pulkovo 1942(58)" was a 1958 re-adjustment of Pulkovo 1942 in eastern Europe client states of the former USSR.

Parameters, etc. are exactly the same for the two systems.

Disclosure: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org).